# Customize underline pattern in NSAttributedString (iOS7+)

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring, underline, textkit

I'm trying to add a dotted underline style to an `NSAttributedString` (on iOS7+/TextKit). Of course, I tried the built-in `NSUnderlinePatternDot`:

```
NSString *string = self.label.text;
NSRange underlineRange = [string rangeOfString:@"consetetur sadipscing elitr"];

NSMutableAttributedString *attString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string];
[attString addAttributes:@{NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle | NSUnderlinePatternDot)} range:underlineRange];

self.label.attributedText = attString;
```

However, the style produced by this is actually rather dashed than dotted:

[image: screenshot]

Am I missing something obvious here (`NSUnderlinePatternReallyDotted`? ;) ) or is there perhaps a way to customize the line-dot-pattern?

Answer (score 4):

According to Eiko&Dave's answer, [i made an example like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gumiG.png)

i've try to finish that by using UILabel rather than UITextView, but could not find a solution after searching from stackoverflow or other websites. So, i used UITextView to do that.

```
    let storage = NSTextStorage()
    let layout = UnderlineLayout()
    storage.addLayoutManager(layout)
    let container = NSTextContainer()
    container.widthTracksTextView = true
    container.lineFragmentPadding = 0
    container.maximumNumberOfLines = 2
    container.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
    layout.addTextContainer(container)

    let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width-40, height: 50), textContainer: container)
    textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    textView.isEditable = false
    textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    textView.text = "1sadasdasdasdasdsadasdfdsf"
    textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    let rg = NSString(string: textView.text!).range(of: textView.text!)
    let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle.rawValue: 0x11,
                      NSAttributedString.Key.underlineColor: UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.2),
                      NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black, NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17),
                      NSAttributedString.Key.baselineOffset:10] as! [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]

    storage.addAttributes(attributes, range: rg)
    view.addSubview(textView)
```

override LayoutManage Method

```
class UnderlineLayout: NSLayoutManager {
    override func drawUnderline(forGlyphRange glyphRange: NSRange, underlineType underlineVal: NSUnderlineStyle, baselineOffset: CGFloat, lineFragmentRect lineRect: CGRect, lineFragmentGlyphRange lineGlyphRange: NSRange, containerOrigin: CGPoint) {
    if let container = textContainer(forGlyphAt: glyphRange.location, effectiveRange: nil) {
        let boundingRect = self.boundingRect(forGlyphRange: glyphRange, in: container)
        let offsetRect = boundingRect.offsetBy(dx: containerOrigin.x, dy: containerOrigin.y)

        let left = offsetRect.minX
        let bottom = offsetRect.maxY-15
        let width = offsetRect.width
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.lineWidth = 3
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: left, y: bottom))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: left + width, y: bottom))
        path.stroke()
    }
}
```

in my solution, i've to expand lineSpacing also keep a customize underline by using NSAttributedString property NSMutableParagraphStyle().lineSpacing, but it seems that didn't work, but NSAttributedString.Key.baselineOffset is worked. hope can

Answer (score 3):

I've spent a little bit of time playing around with Text Kit to get this and other similar scenarios to work. The actual Text Kit solution for this problem is to subclass `NSLayoutManager` and override `drawUnderline(forGlyphRange:underlineType:baselineOffset:lineFragmentRect:lineFragmentGlyphRange:containerOrigin:)`

This is the method that gets called to actually draw the underline that is requested by the attributes in the `NSTextStorage`. Here's a description of the parameters that get passed in:

- **`glyphRange`** the index of the first glyph and the number of following glyphs to be underlined
- **`underlineType`** the `NSUnderlineStyle` value of the `NSUnderlineAttributeName` attribute
- **`baselineOffset`** the distance between the bottom of the bounding box and the baseline offset for the glyphs in the provided range
- **`lineFragmentRect`** the rectangle that encloses the entire line that contains **`glyphRange`**
- **`lineFragmentGlyphRange`** the glyph range that makes up the entire line that contains **`glyphRange`**
- **`containerOrigin`** the offset of the container within the text view to which it belongs

Steps to draw underline:

1. Find the `NSTextContainer` that contains `glyphRange` using `NSLayoutManager.textContainer(forGlyphAt:effectiveRange:)`.
2. Get the bounding rectangle for `glyphRange` using `NSLayoutManager.boundingRect(forGlyphRange:in:)`
3. Offset the bounding rectangle by the text container origin using `CGRect.offsetBy(dx:dy:)`
4. Draw your custom underline somewhere between the bottom of the offset bounding rectangle and the baseline (as determined by `baselineOffset`)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a 2 year old story but maybe it will help someone facing the same problem, like I did last week.
My workaround was to subclass `UITextView`, add a subview (the dotted lines container) and use the textView’s layoutManager method `enumerateLineFragmentsForGlyphRange` to get the number of lines and their frames. 
Knowing the line’s frame I calculated the `y` where I wanted the dots. So I created a view (lineView in which I drawn dots), set `clipsToBounds` to `YES`, the width to that of the textView and then 
added as a subview in the linesContainer at that `y`. 
After that I set the lineView’s `width` to that returned by `enumerateLineFragmentsForGlyphRange`.
For multiple rows the same approach: update frames, add new lines or remove according to what `enumerateLineFragmentsForGlyphRange` returns. 
This method is called in `textViewDidChange` after each text update.
Here is the code to get the array of lines and their frames

```
NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = [self layoutManager];
[layoutManager enumerateLineFragmentsForGlyphRange:NSMakeRange(0, [layoutManager numberOfGlyphs]) 
                                        usingBlock:^(CGRect rect, CGRect usedRect, NSTextContainer *textContainer, NSRange glyphRange, BOOL *stop) {
                                                        [linesFramesArray addObject:NSStringFromCGRect(usedRect)];
                                                   }
];
```