# NSAttributedString with custom underline

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

Is there a way to customize the underline of a NSAttributedString?
I would like to customize:

- Underline color
- Underline width
- Distance between the text and the underline

[image]

Maybe even creating a custom view under text?

Comment: No, `NSAttributedString` does not support custom underlining.

Comment: I don't know of a way provided by NSAttributedString, but what about just using some views to underline the text and placing them at whatever distance you need.

Comment: You can change underline color and underline style(double line or single line etc.)

Comment: You'd have to play with CoreText to do so, override drawRect, TextStorage or other parts like that.

Comment: @Larme, can you please provide a code example and output in an answer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25523910/customize-underline-pattern-in-nsattributedstring-ios7

Comment: @Larme Thanks man, that is exactly what I was looking for. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53330387/1341180. Post it as an answer and I'll approve.

Comment: Since it's the same question, upvote the answers there, and mark your question as duplicate if you think that another user would have better chances to find yours and not the other one (and then see the duplicate link). If not, just delete yours.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Customize underline pattern in NSAttributedString (iOS7+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25523910/customize-underline-pattern-in-nsattributedstring-ios7)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a perfect answer here, just a half proof.

[image]

I add some sample code here:

```
    let text = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: "hello")

    let range = NSMakeRange(0, text.length)
    // add large fonts
    text.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor, value: UIColor.red, range: range)
    text.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.blue, range: range)
    text.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 72), range: range)


    // add underline
    text.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle, value: NSNumber(value:  NSUnderlineStyle.double.rawValue), range: range)
    text.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.underlineColor, value: UIColor.green, range: range)

    textView.attributedText = text
```

Comment: Have you forgotten to post the code to this answer?

Comment: His question has no answer. It’s a proof for my comment.

Comment: There is no code. I changed it in text view preview of IB

Comment: Hey @E.Coms, Thanks for taking the time to answer. The thing is that the text is dynamic and has to be set from the code. Any idea how I can achieve this functionality with code?

Comment: @E.Coms, hey again. What you suggesting is making the fonts bigger so that the underline will be bigger proportionally to the text. What I am looking for is preserving the text side and making only the underline thicker and different distances from the text. Not with preset values, but with custom values.

Comment: I make it bigger just for people can see it. You don’t need to make it bigger. Just use last two line code. I said there is no way to adjust the distance and you only can choose different style.